# Integrate to paypal through web services. That is no HTTP redirect

Tags: .net, paypal

Can someone please clarify how can one integrate to paypal in order to facilitate a payment through paypal directly to the web services, without the http redirect to the paypal site? Can you please indicate which paypal product is necessary and what is the API?
I understand that [direct payment](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPDirectPayments) would do the trick but I am not sure and I can't find what product is that part of, or how can one apply for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayFlow Pro allows you to process payments without roundtrip to PayPal's site.

Overview: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-overview-outside

For Developers: https://www.x.com/community/ppx/payflow_pro

Dev Guide: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_Guide.pdf